# Spring batch auto-generate tables with custom prefix

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have the following:

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" enabled="${banking.data.source.init}">
    <jdbc:script location="${banking.drop.script}" />
    <jdbc:script location="${banking.schema.script}" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>

 <batch:job-repository id="jobRepository"
     data-source="dataSource"
     transaction-manager="transactionManager"
     table-prefix="prefix_"
     isolation-level-for-create="SERIALIZABLE"/>
```

The tables are generated automatically but with the default prefix "BATCH_" and when a job starts the framework searches for the tables with the custom prefix "prefix_".

How can I auto generate the tables with a custom prefix?
Can I do that?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, you can't.  We allow you to configure the prefix in the job repository, but the facility for creating those tables automatically is via static SQL scripts so there is no configurable way to define what that prefix will be when creating the tables.  You'll have to update the provided SQL scripts for your specific environment.