# Spring batch job not creating tables

Tags: spring-batch

I have a configuration class annotated with

The metadata tables are getting created but without table prefix.
Initialize-schema is ALWAYS and table-prefix is CUSTOM_

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JobParametersValidator jobParametersValidator;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String postgresUrl;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String postgresUserName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String postgresPassword;

    private String postgresSchema = "public";


    @Bean("dataSource")
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl(this.postgresUrl);
        hikariDataSource.setUsername(this.postgresUserName);
        hikariDataSource.setPassword(this.postgresPassword);
        hikariDataSource.setSchema(this.postgresSchema);
        return hikariDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return transactionManager;
    }
   
    @Bean
    public Job...


}
```

My application.yml looks like:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: ${APPLICATION_NAME}
  batch:
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: ALWAYS
      table-prefix: CUSTOM_
    job:
      enabled: false
```

What am I missing to initialize the schema with correct table prefix

libraries:
spring-boot-starter-batch:3.0.5
It comprises of spring-batch-core:5.0.1

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716309/spring-batch-auto-generate-tables-with-custom-prefix

Comment: No, that is not a duplicate of that Q/A. I added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

With Spring Boot 3, when you add `@EnableBatchProcessing`, the auto-configuration of Spring Batch (meta-data tables creation, launching of jobs at startup, etc) will back off. As a result, the `spring.batch.*` properties that you have configured do not have any effect.

This is mentioned in the [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#spring-batch-changes) of Spring Boot 3.

Comment: Removing @EnableBatchProcessing annotation solved the problem. Thanks Mahmoud.